# How to extract lines starting with a pattern and chunks between two patterns?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have files (say, `infile.tex`) of the form

```
AAAA
BBBB AAAA
CCCC BBBB AAAA

%%## Just some text
\begin{example}[foobar]
\begin{Sinput}
> set.seed(271)
> U <- runif(10)
> plot(U, 1-U)
\end{Sinput}
AAAA BBBB CCCC
\begin{Sinput}
> plot(qnorm(cbind(U, 1-U)))
\end{Sinput}
\end{example}
```

and I would like to extract all lines starting with `%%##` *and* all lines between `\begin{Sinput}` and `\end{Sinput}`, so

```
%%## Just some text
\begin{Sinput}
> set.seed(271)
> U <- runif(10)
> plot(U, 1-U)
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Sinput}
> plot(qnorm(cbind(U, 1-U)))
\end{Sinput}
```

I tried to work with `sed`:

`sed -n '/%%##\|\\begin{Sinput}/,/\\end{Sinput}/p' infile.tex` # but also contains `\begin{example}[foobar]`

`sed -n '/^%%##\|\\begin{Sinput}/,/\\end{Sinput}/p' infile.tex` # but does not contain lines starting with `%%##`

Note: The above is somewhat derived from [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933656/using-sed-to-print-the-lines-starting-with-two-different-patterns). Also, a 'two-step' solution (first extracting all lines starting with... and then all chunks) might be possible, too (I just didn't see how and it seems that `sed` allows to choose several 'patterns' so that seems more elegant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` with its range operator (,) works pretty well for this.  Tag an extra filter on the end (;) and hey presto.

```
awk '/^\\begin\{Sinput\}/,/^\\end\{Sinput\}/;/^%%##/' infile.tex
%%## Just some text
\begin{Sinput}
> set.seed(271)
> U <- runif(10)
> plot(U, 1-U)
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Sinput}
> plot(qnorm(cbind(U, 1-U)))
\end{Sinput}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I originally also tried with `awk`, but couldn't get it to work either. The `;` is handy.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^\\begin{Sinput}/,/^\\end{Sinput}/!{/^%%##/!d}'

perl -lne 'print if /^\Q\begin{Sinput}/ .. /^\Q\end{Sinput}/ or /^%%##/'
```

The `range` operator in `Perl` is `..`. We use the quote the following text using the `\Q` so that we don't need to explicitly escape the special characters.

## Result

```
%%## Just some text
\begin{Sinput}
> set.seed(271)
> U <- runif(10)
> plot(U, 1-U)
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Sinput}
> plot(qnorm(cbind(U, 1-U)))
\end{Sinput}
```